# Best approach for creating a function from multiple inputs/outputs?

Tags: functions, data-analysis

I have a list of inputs and outputs, and I need to somehow find a function that will match them. There's two inputs and one output per set. At first I considered using a Neural Network, but it might be difficult to get a mathematical function from it, and it wouldn't be perfect.

**Patterns I've noticed:** All of the values are always positive integers, and when `input 1` and `input 2` are the same, the output is always `1`. Typically, the higher `input 1` and `input 2` are, the higher the output is, but I can't figure out by how much exactly.

This is a sample of my data:
|Input 1|Input 2|Output|
|-------|-------|------|
|5      |5      |1     |
|4      |5      |6     |
|3      |5      |2     |
|2      |5      |4     |
|6      |5      |8     |
|6      |6      |1     |
|6      |7      |10    |

I'm not quite sure how to go about this. Does anybody have any suggestions?

**Edit:** The above table is rendering in the question editor, but it won't render for me on the actual question. I'm not sure if this is a local issue or if I messed up the markdown; here's an ASCII version:

```
|Input 1|Input 2|Output|
|-------|-------|------|
|5      |5      |1     |
|4      |5      |6     |
|3      |5      |2     |
|2      |5      |4     |
|6      |5      |8     |
|6      |6      |1     |
|6      |7      |10    |
```

**Edit 2:** As fedja suggested, I compiled a grid of the data (below). There were a few interesting trends that I spotted quickly, like the fact that all the values were mirrored (e.g. `1x3` and `3x1` contain the same value). There was also a pattern I noticed that I put in grey and blue, where it alternates between adding 1 and 2.
[image: 10x10 Data Grid]

Comment: [Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) is a rich subject.

Comment: Which method to choose really depends on whether your goal after that is to make an educated guess about the values at other points based on your data or whether you just want some expression that would allow you to compute the output on existing inputs faster than by searching the data table (note that such expression may not exist in general). Also, it seems like all your input and output values are integer. Is it always the case?

Comment: @fedja Yes, all of the values are always positive integers.

Comment: And which of the two objectives I mentioned do you have in mind (or is it yet some another one altogether?)

Comment: Also, do you have a reasonably large (10 by 10 or more) rectangular chunk of your data D(x,y) around the diagonal x=y (i.e., all or almost all D(i,j) for i,j in some interval [k,k+m] with m>10 (or as large as available if you cannot provide at least 10)? If yes, post it, because your sample is too small and irregular to draw any plausible conclusions from it (too many possibilities to match)

Comment: @fedja My goal is to be able to successfully predict an output based on two given inputs that haven't been seen before. As for the larger data, I'll work on putting it together, but manually collecting it might take a little while.

Comment: @TylerSelden OK, get a larger and more regular (in terms of the distribution of pairs of arguments; a rectangular table with full diagonal would be ideal) data sample, post it, alert me in a comment, and I'll try to run a couple of ideas on it. I guess some other people would think of it too at that point. With the data you provided, it is hopeless: most likely you'll just get plenty of beautiful perfectly matching your sample functions none of which will be even close to the truth.

Comment: @TylerSelden or just tell how exactly you obtain your output, if that process can be reproduced at other locations and is not coming from some crazy experiment whose details other people won't be even able to understand.

Comment: @fedja I added the data in a `10x10` grid to my post, as well as a few patterns I've noticed so far.

Comment: There is enough regularity in the data to suggest a pattern (to me) and not enough to see it (other than symmetry over the diagonal) (if it exists). As @fedja says, [edit] the question to describe how you generated the data we see, and how you plan to get more (even though it will "take a while").

Comment: @EthanBolker Ignore the first row and the first column and shift the "corresponding input values values down by one respectively, so the first row becomes 1,2,3,4,\dots, the second 2,1,4,6,3,8,\dots, etc. Then If i and j (new ones) are relatively prime, we have D(i,j)=i+j-1. The rule when GCD(i,j)>1 still escapes me, but this is a good starting point.

Comment: @EthanBolker also if i divides j, then D(i,j) =j/i, so the only remaining interesting (unexplained) values in this reduced 9 by 9 table are D(4,6)=4, D(6,8)=6 and D(6,9)=4, which doesn't really provide enough information as is, but makes it clear what to request next if we want to continue this game. So, I'd like to see *my* D(i,j) (the OP's D(i+1,j+1)) where i,j are composite, have only prime factors 2,3,5 and are not described by the first two rules The first 10 such numbers are 4,6,8,9,10,14,15,16,18,20,,24 and only the upper part of the table is interesting.

Comment: @EthanBolker Before I see those, I can only make a wild interpolating guess from 2 formulas and 3 extra values, which is $D(i,j)=\frac{i+j}{GCD(i,j)}-1$ (with *my* i,j).